# PHPmaker dynamic user not showing Permission checkbox

Tags: php

**Problem:** I successfully setup the 2 tables required for dynamic permission of PHPmaker software but the dynamic permission didn't display the same as the tutorial stated. Did I miss something?

I know this should be in Phpmaker site forum but right now can't see any link to create new post there. I am also a registered user though.

See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Please read the following topics from PHPMaker Help menu:

   - Tutorial - Advanced Security - User ID Security
   - Tutorial - Advanced Security - Dynamic User Level Security
2. You need to regenerate ALL the script files, including the ones under "Other Files" section of the "Generate" dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

You might have created permission related table manually. Best recommended way is to create those tables using **PHPMaker inbuilt create table feature**, which is available under **Advance Security - User Levels**. Then select User Level section and **Dynamic User Levels** under that. After you check **Enable Dynamic User Levels** option, Create Table button will be available. You can click on that and it will create required tables and auto-set all the fields. This way you won't have any permission related issue.